# Improve android listview performance for refreshing and scrolling

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, refresh

I have a `ListView` which `onItemClick` selected item changes its layout, pops different buttons. If any other item is selected, the previous selected one returns to normal. My `ListView` adapter works fine but refreshing the whole list with `notifyDataSetChanged()` in my adapter takes too much time.

My problem is to refresh only the changed items in the `ListView`. 
And also I would like to have suggestions for better scrolling performance.

Comment: You can change individual items in the data backing the listview, but you can't do anything other that `notifyDataSetChanged()` to inform the adapter that the data has changed.

Comment: try to implement **View Holder Pattern** it increases the performance of loading and scrolling of `ListViews`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to implement **View Holder Pattern** it increases the performance of loading and scrolling of `ListViews`

[Making ListView Scrolling Smooth | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)
[Using lists in Android (ListView) - Tutorial - Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder)

from the docs:

> Your code might call `findViewById()` frequently during the scrolling of `ListView`, which can slow down performance. Even when the Adapter returns an inflated view for recycling, you still need to look up the elements and update them. A way around repeated use of `findViewById()` is to use the **"view holder"** design pattern.

Comment: closest solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can define one method in adapter class which will return current item view. in onitemclick use this method to make changes in clicked item. You can define class view type class variable in activity and store previous view there...

Answer (score 1):

ListView scrolling performance slows down when widgests like textviews, images are at the bottom of the layout hierarchy.

So for improving list performance one should design item xmls with minimum layout tree levels.